# Compare sheets to copy differences

Tags: excel, google-sheets, compare, duplicates, vba

I have this working VBA code that compares 2 sheets and copies duplicates to the 'Changes' sheet. I need to do the opposite. I need to copy differences to the changes sheet.

```
Sub CompareSheets()
Dim Sht1Rng As Range
Dim Sht2Rng As Range

Set Sht1Rng = Worksheets("RXCP Order").Range("A1", Worksheets("RXCP Order").Range("A1000").End(xlUp))
Set Sht2Rng = Worksheets("QS1 Order").Range("A1", Worksheets("QS1 Order").Range("A1000").End(xlUp))

For Each c In Sht1Rng
    Set d = Sht2Rng.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Changes").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c.Value
        Worksheets("Changes").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set d = Nothing
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to find changes from one worksheet to another is to add sheet3 with the following formula in each cell of the used range of sheet1:

```
=if(Sheet1!A1<>Sheet2!A1,1,0)
```

Then add a column to sheet3 adding across the row.
Any rows with a count greater than zero should be copied.
You can filter then copy paste manually or run your for loop down the count column in sheet three and copy the row from sheet two based on the row it is on in sheet 3

```
dim aCell as range
with thisworkbook
for each acell in .sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1:Z1000")
  if acell.value > 0 then
    .sheets("Sheet1").range("A" & acell.row).entirerow.copy _
    .sheets("Sheet4").range("A" & .sheets("Sheet4").usedrange.rows.count + 1)
  end if
next acell
end with
```

You can write a macro to copy the formula above to all the cells in the sheet3's used range, and copy the formula down the next available column also.